# Trouble with setting entry point for GWT service

Tags: java, gwt

I've followed several tutorials and read official docs at code.google.com, but still didn't manage to resolve this thing.

I am creating simple service that'll check if user can be logged.

**CLIENT SIDE:**

```
public interface LoginService extends RemoteService {

    /**
     * Checks, if user has valid login.
     * @param user User's login.
     * @return True if such a login is in the database.
     */
     boolean isValidUser(User user);
}
```

And here is Async interface:

```
public interface LoginServiceAsync {

    /**
     * Checks, if user has valid login.
     * @param user User's login.
     * @param callback the callback to return True if such a login is in the database.
     */
     void isValidUser(User user, AsyncCallback<Boolean> callback);
}
```

**SERVER SIDE:**

```
public class LoginServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements LoginService {

    /**
     * serial version UID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1044980345057997696L;

    /**{@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public boolean isValidUser(User user) {
        boolean success = true; //TODO change
    }

}
```

Now I have entry point class MailClient.java. I append here widget like:

`CustomWidgets.getLoginWidget(this); 
// access rootPanel and append widget`

Now I need to make actual call to my service, **and here is problem:**

```
LoginServiceAsync loginService = (LoginServiceAsync) GWT.create(LoginService.class);
                User user = new User(boxName.getText(), boxPassword.getText());
                AsyncCallback<Boolean> callback = new AsyncCallback<Boolean>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        Window.alert(caught.getMessage()); //TODO change
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Boolean result) {
                        Window.alert("success"); //TODO change
                    }
                };
                ((ServiceDefTarget) loginService).setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"login"); // dunno what should be here
```

So to recap, **I don't know how to set service's entry point**.

Here's my MailClient.gwt.xml file:

```
<module>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard"/> 
    <entry-point class="com.xorty.mailclient.client.MailClient"/>
    <servlet path="/login"
        class="com.xorty.mailclient.server.servlets.LoginServiceImpl" />
    <inherits name="com.xorty.mailclient.MailClient"/>
    <inherits name="com.xorty.mailclient.MailClient"/>
    <inherits name="com.xorty.mailclient.MailClient"/>
    <inherits name="com.xorty.mailclient.MailClient"/>
    <inherits name="com.xorty.mailclient.MailClient"/>
</module>
```

My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>MailClient.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.xorty.mailclient.server.servlets.LoginServiceImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/com.xorty.mailclient.MailClient/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And here is screenshot of project structure:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting your entry point to `"login"` instead of `GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "login"`.

However, I suggest a bit of refactoring because you seem to be using old GWT API. From GWT 1.6 you no longer need to set EntryPoint for services when you are invoking them. Now entry point can be (and usually should be) set once for each service using `RemoteServiceRelativePath` annotation on the service interface. So in your example `LoginService` interface should look like this:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("login")
public interface LoginService extends RemoteService {

     boolean isValidUser(User user);
}
```

After this change you can delete this line:

```
((ServiceDefTarget) loginService).setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"login");
```

Also `servlet` entries are no longer needed in `*.gwt.xml` files. So you can also delete this line:

```
<servlet path="/login" class="com.xorty.mailclient.server.servlets.LoginServiceImpl" />
```

Your web.xml looks ok.

If you are using Eclipe with [GWT plugin](http://code.google.com/eclipse/index.html) you can generate a simple GWT project and look at it - generated projects contain sample code showing how services can be created and invoked. If you are not using GWT plugin I strongly suggest installing it - it will help you a lot.

Comment: Hi, It's actually working as I posted but only on Tomcat. I dunno what's wrong with Jetty (it's shipped with that plugin I think and used as default container) ...

Answer (score 0):

The service entry point is where you servlet exists on your server and is typically configured in a web.xml file.

Here's a rather old tutorial but the servlet configuration is still relevant:

http://lkamal.blogspot.com/2008/09/java-gwt-servlets-web-app-tutorial.html

Comment: @pulazoo I added web.xml to post, still nothing

Comment: It's actually working when deployed on Tomcat. But it doesn' when debugging (Jetty, Google plugin for Eclipse)